# Nul and NUL in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I have a script with following line, From that line it check weather the java version is 1.6 or 1.7. But I am getting error [1], When I further analyze figure out it comes from >NUL, it cannot basically find NUL. But when I replace it with NULL, it works. As I know in windows correct one should be NUL and not NULL. Can anyone tell the reason for this ?

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -version 2>&1 | findstr /r "1.[6|7]" >NUL

I am using 64 bit Windows 7 Professional (Service Pack1).

[1] The system cannot find the file specified

Thanks
Godwin

Comment: And I am getting this problem in only one machine which is specified above and all others work fine.

Comment: If you use NULL it is probably actually writing to a file named NULL.  As for why NUL isn't working, I don't know - perhaps someone has been messing around with that machine.  Try a simpler command, e.g., `echo hello > NUL`

Comment: It doesn't create physical file with name NULL. Looks it behave same as NUL. echo hello > NUL command also gives the same error as "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: I'd say the machine has definitely been messed with in some way.  WinObj (available for download from Microsoft's web site) allows you to look at the device tree, there should be a symbolic link, pointing to to \Device\Null, named NUL in the GLOBAL?? directory.  (There shouldn't be a symbolic link named NULL.)